# skimage is not defined in jupyter notebook despite having installed the module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

I created a virtual environment and installed scikitimage but when i use jupyter notebook it says no modules named skimage.

I installed scikitimage without using virtual enviroment but still jupyter can't find it.

```
from skimage import color, io
    def load(image_path):

        out = image_path

        out = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
        pass


    image1 = load(image1_path)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-08b9c4b0aed1> in <module>
----> 1 image1 = load(image1_path)
      2 image2 = load(image2_path)
      3 
      4 display(image1)
      5 display(image2)

~\Suleman\imageOperations.py in load(image_path)
     21     ### YOUR CODE HERE
     22     # Use skimage io.imread
---> 23     out = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
     24     pass
     25     ### END YOUR CODE

NameError: name 'skimage' is not defined
```

Comment: did you install the package with the jupyter notebook still running? in that case may be you can restart the jupyter kernel.

Comment: No, I installed evrything in one go

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all you need to uninstall `scikit-image`.Then
2. install it via shell/command prompt:

   `pip install scikit-image`
3. If you are running Anaconda or miniconda, open anaconda prompt then run this

   `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image`
4. if these steps aren't working upgrade your pip using

   `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`
5. then follow again from step 1 to 3 that I have mentioned

If these aren't work uninstall `scikit-image` from both `pip` and `conda` then try this in anaconda prompt

1. `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
2. `conda install scikit-image`
3. `conda search scikit-image --channel conda-forge`

Comment: uninstall `scikit-image` again and run this command in anaconda prompt `conda install scikit-image -c scikit-image` hope it will work

Comment: If this isn't work. I have edited my answer.Please try that new one

Answer (score 0):

1. Open CMD (the command prompt)
2. Type `pip install scikit-image` in the CMD window
3. Type `py` in the CMD window
4. Type `import skimage`
5. Go back to your Jupyter notebook for image processing issues